# ValueError: cannot insert key_0, already exists

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I Want to merge these two DataFrame, One of them I have just created from OnehotEncoder, length of both Dataframe is the same.

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
df_Holiday = pd.DataFrame(ohe.fit_transform(df[['StateHoliday']]).toarray() ,
                      columns = ['public holiday', 'Easter holiday','Christmas holiday','No 
                                  Holiday'])

df = df.merge(df_Holiday, on = df.index )
```

but I am getting this on merge

`ValueError: cannot insert key_0, already exists`

Comment: Do you wish to join both dataframes by index?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to replicate the error, but this works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'StateHoliday': ['public', 'easter', 'christmas', 'none']})
ohe = OneHotEncoder()
df_holiday = pd.DataFrame(
    ohe.fit_transform(df[['StateHoliday']]).toarray(),
    columns=['public', 'easter', 'christmas', 'none'])
merged = pd.concat([df, df_holiday], axis=1)
```

(I suspect the `key_0` is getting introduced by something not shown in your code above.)

Comment: yeah! that was resolved. key_0 was created due to my earlier codes, so i removed it. Thanks for the Answer